# Filter a list generated with Tuples

Tags: list-manipulation

I generated with

```
Tuples[{{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, {1, 2, 3, 4, 14}, {1, 2, 3, 4}, {1, 2, 3, 4}, 
       {1, 5, 6, 7, 8}, {5, 6, 7, 8, 10}, {5, 6, 7, 8}, {5, 6, 7, 8}}]
```

elements like `{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8}`, with all the possible combinations but I want to exclude elements with the same numbers in different places like
`{1,1,3,4,5,6,7,8}` or `{1,2,3,5,5,6,7,8}`.
How can I do that in a simple way?

Comment: Possible duplicate (??): http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/2593/advanced-tupling

Comment: @Szabolcs similar but in this one it seems the order of elements matters

Comment: I need the ordered list of elements. {2,1,3,4,5,6,7,8} is not the same of {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8}

Answer (score 14, accepted):

While you've already gotten an answer to your question, filtering out the unwanted tuples after generating all of them can be a huge waste of memory if there are many such tuples. Therefore it may be a better idea to generate only the wanted tuples to begin with. The following function does that:

```
noreptuples[{f_List, r__List}] := 
  Flatten[Function[x, (Prepend[#1, x] & ) /@ noreptuples[DeleteCases[{r}, x, {2}]]] /@ f, 1]

noreptuples[{l_List}] := List /@ l
```

Note that I didn't time this function; it probably is slower for some cases (straightforward Mathematica code vs. likely very optimized code for `Tuples`) and faster for others (due to less elements to process).

For the example in your question, 160000 tuples are generated, from which only 2880 tuples remain. Given that each tuple has 8 numbers, and assuming storage in a packed array (basically, 4 bytes per integer), you are generating an array of almost 5 megabytes, and after filtering keep only about 90 kilobytes of that. Given that the memory needed for the tuples grows exponentially with tuple length, this means that the filtering method may quickly become impractical.

Answer (score 11):

Another possibility:

```
Select[elements, DeleteDuplicates[#] == # &]
```

with `elements` as defined by [Rojo](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/109/rojo)

```
elements = Tuples[{{1, 2, 3}, {1, 4, 5}, {2, 4, 8}}]
```

Comment: +1, neater. Made me realise that comparing the whole expression is faster than comparing lengths, at least for these short tuples.

Answer (score 9):

```
elements = Tuples[{{1, 2, 3}, {1, 4, 5}, {2, 4, 8}}]
```

This could do it

```
DeleteCases[elements, l_/;l=!=DeleteDuplicates[l]]
```

Comment: Thank you Rojo. It works after you made the Tuples command. I need something that can exclude the generation of such elemends during the execution of the Tuples command

Comment: @RaffaeleCarlone, if that's what you want, then check celtschk answer

Comment: I am not able to find celtschk answer. Where is it?

Answer (score 7):

Here's another solution:

`elements = Tuples[{{1, 2, 3}, {1, 4, 5}, {2, 4, 8}}]`

`DeleteCases[
 elements, _?(Max[Last /@ Tally[#]] > 1 &)]`

Answer (score 2):

```
list = Tuples[{{1, 2, 3}, {1, 4, 5}, {2, 4, 8}}];
```

Since V 10.0 there is `DuplicateFreeQ`:

```
Select[DuplicateFreeQ] @ list
```

{{1, 4, 2}, {1, 4, 8}, {1, 5, 2}, {1, 5, 4}, {1, 5, 8}, {2, 1, 4}, {2,
1, 8}, {2, 4, 8}, {2, 5, 4}, {2, 5, 8}, {3, 1, 2}, {3, 1, 4}, {3,
1, 8}, {3, 4, 2}, {3, 4, 8}, {3, 5, 2}, {3, 5, 4}, {3, 5, 8}}

Answer (score 0):

Using `Cases`:

```
list = Tuples[{{1, 2, 3}, {1, 4, 5}, {2, 4, 8}}]

Cases[list, x_ /; DuplicateFreeQ[x]] === Select[DuplicateFreeQ] @ list

(*True*)
```